# Check Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors are correct

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have a matrix:

```
J = {{0, -λ (1 + φ)/τ}, {-(1 + φ)/τ, δ}};
```

And I compute the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors as follows:

```
e = Eigenvalues[J]
v = Eigenvectors[J]
```

Then I want to check that everything makes sense but this expression returns False. What am I doing wrong?

```
J.v[[1]] === e[[1]]*v[[1]]
```

Comment: Try `{e, v} = Eigensystem[J]` to make sure they are matched.

Comment: `===` is for structural equality, `==` is for mathematical equality. Use the latter. Next time please post copyable code instead of (or in addition to) the image.

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code instead of picture.

Comment: Try `Simplify[J . v[[1]]] === Simplify[e[[1]]*v[[1]]]` or `ApplySides[Simplify, J . v[[1]] == e[[1]]*v[[1]]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
J = {{0, -λ (1 + φ)/τ}, {-(1 + φ)/τ, δ}};

{e, v} = Eigensystem[J];

J . v[[1]] == e[[1]] v[[1]] // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)

J . v[[2]] == e[[2]] v[[2]] // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: Thanks. This does it.

Comment: The point of this answer, @Nicolo, is that if you need both eigenvalues and eigenvectors, you should just use `Eigensystem[]` at the outset instead of computing them separately.